# How do I add a URL prefix (/wiki) to MoinMoin running on uWSGI and nginx?

Tags: nginx, wiki, wsgi, uwsgi, moinmoin

I just set up uWSGI and nginx (with the uWSGI module) and would like to get MoinMoin set up. I'm running uWSGI with MoinMoin with the command below:

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi -s moin.sock --wsgi-file wiki/server/moin.wsgi -M -p 4
```

In nginx, I have it set up like this:

```
location / {
   uwsgi_pass unix:///mnt/moin/moin.sock;
   include uwsgi_params;
}
```

If I wanted MoinMoin to run on the root of my server, this would work fine, but I want my MoinMoin to run on **/wiki** rather than **/**.  I changed my nginx config to reflect this:

```
location /wiki {
   uwsgi_pass unix:///mnt/moin/moin.sock;
   include uwsgi_params;
}
```

After restarting both server, the links in MoinMoin still want to go to **/PageName** rather than **/wiki/PageName**. I would think I would have to specify a setting in MoinMoin. I saw there is a **url_prefix_static** option for **wikiconfig.py**, but am not sure if that is deprecated or if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moinmoin/uWSGI example has been updated to include suburi configuration

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example#MoinMoinonlinenow

Answer (score 0):

According to [this howto](http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick) `url_prefix_static` is the official way for doing this.

Comment: That only changes the prefix of the static files. If I click on an internal link to a different wiki page, it still takes me to **/WikiPage** instead of **/wiki/WikiPage**

Comment: Oh, I see. You should also change `WSGIScriptAlias /  /path/to/your/moin.wsgi` to `WSGIScriptAlias /wiki   /path/to/your/moin.wsgi` in your Apache config.

Comment: I'm using nginx, not Apache

Comment: Try to add `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /wiki;` to your `location` section

Comment: So now the content is linked correctly, but the static content doesn't work. What should I set for `url_prefix_static`? No matter what I put it seems to think it's a wiki page. Also, what does `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /wiki;` even do?

Answer (score 0):

The sample wikiconfig.py shows how to fix url_prefix_static for non-root-URL wikis.

Comment: Which sample wikiconfig.py?